How can I change the prefix key in Workgroups?
For Workgroups, this prefix key works:
(setq wg-prefix-key (kbd "C-c w"))

, but I want to use a different prefix, so I've tried these:
(setq wg-prefix-key "C-M-w w")
(setq wg-prefix-key (kbd "C-M-w w"))


, but none of them work.
I just get C-M-w w is undefined in the Echo Area.
EDIT: I tried to do an interactive customization and I get this:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Key sequence C - M - w SPC w starts with non-prefi...")
  global-set-key("C-M-w w" (keymap (backtab . icicle-complete-keys) (63 . wg-help) (33 . wg-reset) (65 . wg-rename-workgroup) (109 . wg-echo-last-message) (13 . wg-echo-last-message) (86 . wg-echo-version) (116 . wg-echo-time) (20 . wg-echo-time) (101 . wg-echo-all-workgroups) (5 . wg-echo-all-workgroups) (69 . wg-echo-current-workgroup) (33554437 . wg-echo-current-workgroup) (23 . wg-toggle-morph) (9 . wg-toggle-mode-line) (43 . wg-reverse-frame-horizontally-and-vertically) (45 . wg-reverse-frame-vertically) (124 . wg-reverse-frame-horizontally) (62 . wg-move-window-forward) (60 . wg-move-window-backward) (100 . wg-dired) (98 . wg-get-by-buffer) (2 . wg-get-by-buffer) (33554438 . wg-find-file-read-only) (6 . wg-find-file) (83 . wg-update-all-workgroups-and-save) (12 . wg-load) (19 . wg-save) (67108910 . wg-offset-right) (67108908 . wg-offset-left) (24 . wg-swap-workgroups) (97 . wg-switch-to-previous-workgroup) (1 . wg-switch-to-previous-workgroup) (110 . wg-switch-right) (14 . wg-switch-right) (112 . wg-switch-left) (16 . wg-switch-left) (57 . wg-switch-to-index-9) (56 . wg-switch-to-index-8) (55 . wg-switch-to-index-7) (54 . wg-switch-to-index-6) (53 . wg-switch-to-index-5) (52 . wg-switch-to-index-4) (51 . wg-switch-to-index-3) (50 . wg-switch-to-index-2) (49 . wg-switch-to-index-1) (48 . wg-switch-to-index-0) (106 . wg-switch-to-index) (10 . wg-switch-to-index) ...))
  wg-set-prefix-key()
  #f(compiled-function (sym val) #<bytecode 0x116eb8063e606332>)(wg-prefix-key "C-M-w w")
  custom-variable-set((custom-variable :documentation-shown t :custom-state modified :tag #("Wg Prefix Key" 0 13 (custom-data wg-prefix-key)) :value wg-prefix-key :custom-form edit :custom-magic (custom-magic :args (nil) :parent #1 :indent 0 :children ((choice-item :help-echo "Change the state of this item." :format "%[%t%]" :button-prefix widget-push-button-prefix :button-suffix widget-push-button-suffix :mouse-down-action widget-magic-mouse-down-action :tag " State " :parent #14 :indent 0 :button-overlay #<overlay from 242 to 249 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 242 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 249 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>)) :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 239 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 318 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :buttons nil :value nil) :buttons ((custom-group-link :args nil :value workgroups :tag #("Workgroups" 0 10 (custom-data workgroups)) :parent #1 :indent 0 :button-overlay #<overlay from 353 to 363 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 353 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 363 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>) (documentation-string :args nil :value "Workgroups' prefix key." :indent 3 :visibility-widget custom-visibility :parent #1 :doc-overlay #<overlay from 318 to 344 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :buttons nil :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 318 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 345 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>) (custom-magic :args (nil) :parent #1 :indent 0 :children ((choice-item :help-echo "Change the state of this item." :format "%[%t%]" :button-prefix widget-push-button-prefix :button-suffix widget-push-button-suffix :mouse-down-action widget-magic-mouse-down-action :tag " State " :parent #19 :indent 0 :button-overlay #<overlay from 242 to 249 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 242 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 249 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>)) :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 239 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 318 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :buttons nil :value nil) (item :format "%{%t%}: " :action custom-tag-action :help-echo "Change value of this option." :mouse-down-action custom-tag-mouse-down-action :button-face custom-variable-button :sample-face custom-variable-tag :tag #("Wg Prefix Key" 0 13 (custom-data wg-prefix-key)) :parent #1 :indent 0 :sample-overlay #<overlay from 208 to 221 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 208 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 223 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>) (custom-visibility :args nil :value t :help-echo "Hide or show this option." :on "Hide" :off "Show" :on-glyph "down" :off-glyph "right" :action custom-toggle-hide-variable :parent #1 :indent 0 :suppress-face t :button-overlay #<overlay from 203 to 207 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 203 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 207 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>)) :documentation-indent 3 :comment-widget (custom-comment :parent #1 :value "" :indent 0 :from #<marker at 345 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 345 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>) :children ((string :value "\32" :parent #1 :indent 0 :sample-overlay #<overlay from 223 to 229 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :field-overlay #<overlay from 231 to 238 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 223 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 239 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>) (custom-comment :parent #1 :value "" :indent 0 :from #<marker at 345 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 345 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>)) :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 203 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 364 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :comment-shown nil))
  #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_16>((custom-variable :documentation-shown t :custom-state modified :tag #("Wg Prefix Key" 0 13 (custom-data wg-prefix-key)) :value wg-prefix-key :custom-form edit :custom-magic (custom-magic :args (nil) :parent #1 :indent 0 :children ((choice-item :help-echo "Change the state of this item." :format "%[%t%]" :button-prefix widget-push-button-prefix :button-suffix widget-push-button-suffix :mouse-down-action widget-magic-mouse-down-action :tag " State " :parent #14 :indent 0 :button-overlay #<overlay from 242 to 249 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 242 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 249 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>)) :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 239 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 318 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :buttons nil :value nil) :buttons ((custom-group-link :args nil :value workgroups :tag #("Workgroups" 0 10 (custom-data workgroups)) :parent #1 :indent 0 :button-overlay #<overlay from 353 to 363 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 353 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 363 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>) (documentation-string :args nil :value "Workgroups' prefix key." :indent 3 :visibility-widget custom-visibility :parent #1 :doc-overlay #<overlay from 318 to 344 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :buttons nil :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 318 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 345 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>) (custom-magic :args (nil) :parent #1 :indent 0 :children ((choice-item :help-echo "Change the state of this item." :format "%[%t%]" :button-prefix widget-push-button-prefix :button-suffix widget-push-button-suffix :mouse-down-action widget-magic-mouse-down-action :tag " State " :parent #19 :indent 0 :button-overlay #<overlay from 242 to 249 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 242 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 249 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>)) :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 239 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 318 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :buttons nil :value nil) (item :format "%{%t%}: " :action custom-tag-action :help-echo "Change value of this option." :mouse-down-action custom-tag-mouse-down-action :button-face custom-variable-button :sample-face custom-variable-tag :tag #("Wg Prefix Key" 0 13 (custom-data wg-prefix-key)) :parent #1 :indent 0 :sample-overlay #<overlay from 208 to 221 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 208 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 223 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>) (custom-visibility :args nil :value t :help-echo "Hide or show this option." :on "Hide" :off "Show" :on-glyph "down" :off-glyph "right" :action custom-toggle-hide-variable :parent #1 :indent 0 :suppress-face t :button-overlay #<overlay from 203 to 207 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 203 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 207 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>)) :documentation-indent 3 :comment-widget (custom-comment :parent #1 :value "" :indent 0 :from #<marker at 345 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 345 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>) :children ((string :value "\32" :parent #1 :indent 0 :sample-overlay #<overlay from 223 to 229 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :field-overlay #<overlay from 231 to 238 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 223 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 239 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>) (custom-comment :parent #1 :value "" :indent 0 :from #<marker at 345 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 345 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*>)) :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 203 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 364 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :comment-shown nil))
  custom-command-apply(#<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_16> "Set all values according to this buffer? ")
  Custom-set((push-button :tag " Apply " :help-echo "Apply settings (for the current session only)." :action Custom-set :notify #f(compiled-function (widget) #<bytecode -0x1d4349553160ce7a>) :button-overlay #<overlay from 177 to 184 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 177 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 184 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :inactive nil) nil)
  widget-apply-action((push-button :tag " Apply " :help-echo "Apply settings (for the current session only)." :action Custom-set :notify #f(compiled-function (widget) #<bytecode -0x1d4349553160ce7a>) :button-overlay #<overlay from 177 to 184 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 177 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :to #<marker at 184 in *Customize Option: Wg Prefix Key*> :inactive nil) nil)
  Custom-newline(182)
  funcall-interactively(Custom-newline 182)
  call-interactively(Custom-newline nil nil)
  command-execute(Custom-newline)

How should I specify it, in this customization buffer?
I've tried (kbd "C-M-w w") and "C-M-w w" and unquoted, but they all throw that prefix error.

The default is C-z and you need to use customize or call wg-set-prefix-key afterwards. Untested.

I'm not sure I understand. You mean customize as in M-x customize, which is an interactive operation? I can't set this in code? Also, what does "call wg-set* afterwards" mean? After what?;)

customize can be done interactively, but it can also be done programmatically: check what appears in your custom file when you do an interactive customization. The point here is that setting the variable with setq is not enough: you have to call wg-set-prefix-key afterwards manually - or let customize take care of that. That's why some people recommend that people (particularly newbies) should always use customize instead of setq: it deals with the simple case just as well as setq but it also handles the more complicated case - like the one in your question.

I should have said: "...That's why some people recommend that people (particularly newbies) should always  use customize instead of setq for user options (i.e. those that are defined with defcustom)". When you see "You can customize this variable" in the doc string of a variable, you know that it is such a user option.

C-M-w is bound to a command (append-next-kill by default): it is not a prefix key. If you want it to be a prefix key, then make it one (but you'll loose the command that it was bound to) e.g. (define-key global-map (kbd "C-M-w") (make-sparse-keymap)). Then you can add things under it.

I have so many unanswered questions, here, so I just have to start with this: How come I have like 15 commands bound to C-M-w a, C-M-w b, C-M-w c, etc, but I have never defined a prefix for C-M-w? I have had to do it for other combinations of C-M-, but not with "w". So, basically, it already is a prefix; shouldn't it just work, then?

I don't know: I don't know what you've done before and what you are doing now. I thought I'd give you a hint: if that was not enough, I apologize. But I've done enough guessing and it seems I've been wrong with my guesses so far, so I'm not going to guess my way any further into this.

I just noticed that Emacs complains not about C-M-w w but about C - M - w SPC w, which is completely different, Maybe you are missing a kbd call: (kbd "C-M-w w"). Hope that helps.

ok, I have no idea why it's working now, all of a sudden. I've been at this problem for a very long time, but indeed, it works now. Thanks a bunch
